# ¿Por qué me imprime solamente cinco caracteres?

Tags: c

El objetivo es imprimir la palabra al revés y lo que deseo entender es el porque de la situación con el `printf`. Sería de mucha amabilidad que me explicaran ya que creo que debería imprimir carácter por carácter pero en el último solo llega a 5 caracteres y no imprime más que esa cantidad.

```
char letras[11];
gets(letras);

char letras3[11];

char normal;
short c;
for(c=0; c<10; c++){
    normal = letras[9-c];
    if(normal>96 && normal <123){
        printf("%c", normal);
    }

}

printf("\n");

short b;
for(b=0; b<10; b++){
    letras3[9-b] = letras[b]; 
    if(letras3[b]>96 && letras3[b] <123){
        printf("%c", letras3[b]);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema fue porque en la ultima impresión estaba guardando mal el valor del array letras.

La **solución** quedaría así:

```
short b;
for(b=0; b<10; b++){
    letras3[b] = letras[9-b]; //Aquí
    if(letras3[b]>96 && letras3[b]<123){
        printf("%c", letras3[b]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No olvides de aceptar tu respuesta como la correcta.